# Determining optimum period for DCA

Tags: starting-out-investing, dollar-cost-averaging

I have a non-trivial amount of money which I want to transfer from cash deposits into ETFs.

I understand that investing a fixed amount each month (DCA) is the best way to go about this for someone that doesn't want to become a professional securities analyst.

So, the question then becomes: how long should this transfer process take? In other words, should I invest $20K/month and be done in 1 year or only $5K/month and be done in 4 years? More? Less? How do I decide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal time period is unambiguously zero seconds.  **Put it all in immediately.**

Dollar cost averaging reduces the risk that you will be buying at a bad time (no one knows whether now is a bad or great time), but brings with it reduction in expected return because you will be keeping a lot of money in cash for a long time.  You are reducing your risk and your expected return by dollar cost averaging.

It's not crazy to trade expected returns for lower risk.  People do it all the time.  However, if you have a pot of money you intend to invest and you do so over a period of time, then you are changing your risk profile over time in a way that doesn't correspond to changes in your risk preferences.  This is contrary to finance theory and is not optimal.  The optimal percentage of your wealth invested in risky assets is proportional to your tolerance for risk and should not change over time unless that tolerance changes.

Dollar cost averaging makes sense if you are setting aside some of your income each month to invest.  In that case it is simply a way of being invested for as long as possible.  Having a pile of money sitting around while you invest it little by little over time is a misuse of dollar-cost averaging.

**Bottom line: forcing dollar cost averaging on a pile of money you intend to invest is not based in sound finance theory**.  If you want to invest all that money, do so now.  If you are too risk averse to put it all in, then decide how much you will invest, invest that much now, and keep the rest in a savings account indefinitely.  Don't change your investment allocation proportion unless your risk aversion changes.

There are many people on the internet and elsewhere who preach the gospel of dollar cost averaging, but their belief in it is not based on sound principles.  It's just a dogma. The language of your question implies that you may be interested in sound principles, so I have given you the real answer.

Comment: It's not "dollar-cost averaging" per se that's a bad idea; it's "waiting to invest when you want to invest" that's a bad idea.  If you get $100/month that you know you want to invest, but you put it under your mattress to invest at the end of the year because you've heard that "dollar-cost averaging is bad", then that's wrong.  You should invest that $100 each month.  This happens to produce an effect called dollar-cost averaging, and yet it's also the right thing to do.

Comment: @dg99 Agreed.   Will change a few words in the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @farnsy do you have any citations for the assertion that DCA on a pile of money "is not based in sound finance theory"?

Comment: @RonJohn DCA proponents have the burden of proof in this case.  Spend the day reading DCA recommendations and you will never find any theory to back it up.  Finance theory unambiguously says your investment allocation depends (only) on your risk aversion.  Changing your allocation over a nontrivial period of time from all in cash to all equity while your risk aversion remains constant flies in the face of this result.

Comment: just to pile on (agree the DCA concept is way oversold...pun intended), the investor has to make an individual choice for their reward vs. risk first and foremost. If risk tolerance is zero, buy treasuries with all money right now. If risk tolerance is non-zero, find a few well priced ETF/mutual funds to diversify in. If risk tolerance is high, buy bitcoin. All that said, it's reward vs. risk